# JHipster: OIDC Authentication Vs JHipster UAA: Stateful Vs Stateless, How?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microservices, jhipster

Can Anybody please help bring the clarity on the following topic?

the following documentation
https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#oauth2
states that

> OAuth is a stateful security mechanism, like HTTP Session.

And In the JHipster UAA documentation
https://www.jhipster.tech/using-uaa/
states the following

> JHipster UAA is a user accounting and authorizing service for securing
>   JHipster microservices using the OAuth2 authorization protocol.

And it has

> Statelessness

feature

The question is Which part of the above solutions is actually deciding the Stateful Vs Stateless nature?

Please provide detailed information if possible